# Triple Display setup - cursor flickering

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, displaylink

I have Kubuntu 16.04 installed on a Lenovo Yoga 460 with two external monitors connected via hdmi. Everything works good so far. But when switching on the second monitor, the mouse cursor flickers when i enter the laptop screen and first monitor. On the second monitor everything works as expected.

I tried switching output module in Compositor settings from OpenGL 2.0 to OpenGL 3.1, and then from OpenGL 3.1 to Xrandr, but with no effect, the flickering still occurs.
Only when switching off the second monitor, the flickering stops.

I can't figure out whats wrong with my setup. So, how can I possibly fix the cursor flickering on 2 of three displays?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue on Elementary OS and now again on Ubuntu 18.04 where there is a black block behind the cursor. On Elementary I managed to find a workaround by loging out and in again after every reboot. A bit annoying, but at least it got my triple monitor setup working, which I haven't been able to do on Ubuntu 18.04 yet.